# className object has no attribute "" error

Tags: python

```
class Osoba:
    def __init__(self, name=None, surname=None, nrTel=None):

        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.nrTel = nrTel

    def wypiszOsobe(self):
        if self.name or self.surname or self.nrTel:
            print("\tInformation about person:")
            if self.name:
                print(f"\t\tName: {self.name}")
            if self.surname:
                print(f"\t\tSurname: {self.surname}")
            if self.nrTel:
                print(f"\t\tPhone number: {self.nrTel}")
            print()
        else:
            print("\tNo info about person.")


o = Osoba("Rostyslav", nrTel = "500 600 700")
o.wypiszOsobe()

o2 = Osoba("Adam", "Kowalski")
o2.wypiszOsobe()

#del o.name

o.wypiszOsobe()
```

Comment: After you deleted the `imię` attribute, `wypiszOsobe()` will fail because the very first thing it does is try to use the `imię` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the whole `imię` attribute of `o`, just set it to `None` (or an empty string `''`):

```py
# del o.imię
o.imię = None
```

That way, `if self.imię` won't throw an error but evaluate as `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Osoba:

    def __init__(self,imię,nazwisko,nrTel):
        self.imię = imię
        self.nazwisko = nazwisko
        self.nrTel = nrTel

    def wypiszOsobe(self):
        if self.imię or self.nazwisko or self.nrTel: #something wrong in this line
            print("\tInformation about person:")
            if self.imię:
                print(f"\t\tName: {self.imię}")
            if self.nazwisko:
                print(f"\t\tSurname: {self.nazwisko}")
            if self.nrTel:
                print(f"\t\tPhone number: {self.nrTel}")
            print()
        else:
            print("\tNo info about person.")

o = Osoba("Rostyslav",nazwisko="give a value here", nrTel = "500 600 700")
o.wypiszOsobe()

o2 = Osoba("Adam", "Kowalski", nrTel = "give something here too")
o2.wypiszOsobe()
```

Comment: what about del method? without it, it works fine

Comment: the del method works buh calling the object method after you have delete an object attribute will definitely bring an error